# Custom MapAnnotation leads to "[SwiftUI] Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed, this will cause undefined behavior"

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapkit

If I use the default `MapMarker`, the map works fine. However, if I use a simple custom `MapAnnotation` the map becomes extremely slow and the error fowling error message is shown countless times as I move around the map.

> [SwiftUI] Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed, this will cause undefined behavior"

My code is the following:

```
struct UNESCOUIView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject private var UM: UNESCOModel
    @State var isShowingMapView = false
 
    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
           //code
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingMapView) {
            MapUNUIView(UNsites: $UM.UNESCOSites, isShowingMapView: $isShowingMapView)
        }
    }



struct MapUNUIView: View {
    
    @Binding var UNsites:[UNESCOSite]
    @Binding var isShowingMapView: Bool
    
    @State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.507222, longitude: -0.1275), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 10, longitudeDelta: 10))
    

    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            Map(coordinateRegion: $region, showsUserLocation: true, annotationItems: $UNsites) { $place in
                 // works fine with this
                //MapMarker(coordinate: place.coordinate)

                // doesn't work with this
                MapAnnotation(coordinate:  place.coordinate) {
                Circle()
                 .strokeBorder(.red, lineWidth: 4)
                 .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
           }
        }.ignoresSafeArea(.all)

        }
    }
```

If I try the following, the problem remains.

```
    let binding = Binding(
      get: { self.UNsites },
      set: { newValue in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          self.UNsites = newValue
        }
      }
    )
    return Map(coordinateRegion: $region, annotationItems: binding) { $place in
        
        //MapMarker(coordinate: place.coordinate)

        MapAnnotation(coordinate:  place.coordinate) {
            Circle()
                .strokeBorder(.red, lineWidth: 4)
                .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue, seems to be that this fixes it (I don't really understand why, so if someone can explain why it works and why the previous way of doing it now doesn't that would be really appreciated)

I don't take credit for this, as it was a solution by another user called  `tonyayoub` on the [Apple developer forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/711899?answerId=732977022#732977022)

This is what he found, the code that was producing the warning was:

```
struct AreaMap: View {

  @Binding var region: MKCoordinateRegion

  var body: some View {
    Map(coordinateRegion: $region)
  }
}
```

Where region was passed in the initializer of AreaMap from its parent view.
This resolved the issue:

```
struct AreaMap: View {

  @Binding var region: MKCoordinateRegion

  var body: some View {
    let binding = Binding(
      get: { self.region },
      set: { newValue in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          self.region = newValue
        }
      }
    )
    return Map(coordinateRegion: binding)
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I've added how I implemented your suggestion but the problem remains..