# SwiftUI Map() MapAnnotation vs MapPin (or Annotation vs Marker)

Tags: swift, swiftui

There are several questions on similar topic already and some answers but I still am not able to make it work for me.  Issue is with the annoying "Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed, this will cause undefined behavior." error

This is the one matching the closest
[Custom MapAnnotation leads to "[SwiftUI] Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed, this will cause undefined behavior"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74164625/custom-mapannotation-leads-to-swiftui-publishing-changes-from-within-view-upd)

This is my Annotation

```
struct MyAnnotation: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
}
```

This is the viewModel

```
extension CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    static let ch = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 43.653734011477184, longitude: -79.38415146943686)
    static let rc = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 43.64190399683823,  longitude: -79.38917588924176)
    static let sba = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 43.64358280036363, longitude: -79.37910987946465)
}

class AnnotationViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    @Published var annotations = [
        MyAnnotation(name: "CITY HALL", coordinate: .ch),
        MyAnnotation(name: "ROGERS CENTER", coordinate: .rc),
        MyAnnotation(name: "SCOTIABANK ARENA", coordinate: .sba)
    ]
}
```

And this is my Map view

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var annotationViewModel = AnnotationViewModel()
    @State var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: .ch, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.05, longitudeDelta: 0.05))
    
    var body: some View {

        Map(coordinateRegion: $region, annotationItems: annotationViewModel.annotations) {

//            MapPin(coordinate: $0.coordinate)

            MapAnnotation(coordinate: $0.coordinate) {
                Image(systemName: "t.circle.fill")
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

I want to use MapAnnotation as it is tappable and MapPin is not (afaik)..and it is the same with Annotation and Marker in iOS17.

The error "[SwiftUI] Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed, this will cause undefined behavior." shows up with MapAnnotation but not with MapPin.

Is the fix at the link above the way to go, or is there another way?  I've been trying for a few days without success and tbh don't really know how to apply that fix in my particular case.

Comment: This really needs a [Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The code that you supplied does not build.

Comment: I was missing the extension.  The error is not as pronounced here but with iOS17 Annotation it shows up twice for every annotation when following the WWDC23 example, so you can imagine it could get really annoying.

Comment: Remove the `@Published` from `annotations`. That is causing the error. When an annotation is tapped, `@Published` is firing, causing a view update because the `annotationViewModel` is a `StateObject`.

Comment: Error shows when annotation is first shown, no tapping needed. I can't remove @Published because annotations are in AnnotationViewModel...in this example statically defined but in practice from a network API.   Or is there another way to do this without @Published?

Comment: So, your concern is to update the UI when `annotations` is updated from an API call? You can make a variable, that is published, in AnnotationViewModel and update that when the data comes in. You can then make your view `.id()` use that to cause a refresh.

Comment: But isn’t that what I’m already doing by publishing ‘annotations’?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254092/discussion-between-yrb-and-user8865059).